# How to reassemble a pandas dataframe based on a non-ordered index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have been working on an algorithm that separates rows in a dataframe based on one of the columns to treat them differently. The results should be reassembled afterwards. I need to make sure that the index is preserved and in the same order.

Initially I thought I could just concatenate the results and then put the index in the same order. However, I cannot find an efficient way to do this. The best I could come up with is this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Input data with non-ordered index.
input_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'type': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'],
    'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
}, index=[0, 10, 40, 30, 20])
# input_data:
#    type  value
# 0     a      1
# 10    a      2
# 40    b      3
# 30    c      4
# 20    a      5

# Data separated into two and treated differently.
data_a = input_data[input_data['type'] == 'a']
data_a['result'] = data_a['value'].mean()
data_b = input_data[input_data['type'] != 'a'] 
data_b['result'] = data_b['value'].max()

# Assemble output.
output_data = (
    pd.DataFrame(index=input_data.index) # correct index order
    .merge(
        pd.concat(
            [data_a['result'], data_b['result']], axis=0
        ), # wrong index order
        how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True # 'left' preserves order
    )
)
# output_data:
#       result
# 0   2.666667
# 10  2.666667
# 40  4.000000
# 30  4.000000
# 20  2.666667
```

Is there a more straight-forward way to do this? Or perhaps more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) if index values are unique:

```
output_data  = pd.concat([data_a['result'], data_b['result']]).reindex(input_data.index)
```